# Volume of a solid by revolution (cylindrical shells)

Tags: calculus, integration, solid-geometry, solid-of-revolution

I frequent Stack Overflow, but I am new here. I was given this problem:

Use the method of cylindrical shells to find the volume $V$ generated by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the specified axis.
$x = 2y^2$, $y \geq 0$, $x = 2$;  about $y = 2$

My setup for the problem is $2\pi \displaystyle\int_0^2(2-y)(2y^2) dy$. I derived this from $V=2\pi rh$ where $r = 2-y$ and $h=x=2y^2$. I've solved this to get $\frac{16\pi}{3}$ but that answer seems to be incorrect.

Disclaimer: While I appreciate answers, I don't just want "The answer is: ...." I want to know WHY my setup is incorrect. Also, if someone could format this for me that would be very helpful, as I am unfamiliar with MathJax. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it. The correct setup is

$$2\pi \int_0^{\color{red}1}(2-y)\underbrace{(2-2y^2)}_{\text{"height"}~h} dy$$

The "height" of the cylinder is from the parabolic boundary $x = 2y^2$ on the "left" to the $x=2$ on the "right". Note the upper integration limit is $1$, again due to $x = 2y^2$ meeting $x=2$ giving $x = 2 = 2y^2 \implies y = 1$ (and also $y$ is restricted to be positive).

Comment: If a diagram or anything else is needed, please let me know.

Comment: No, this was very helpful! I think bounds are where I get stuck usually, so I took a look at your answer after graphing it and it was very clear, I should be able to figure out this sort of problems in the future, thank you!

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin Im having trouble visualizing this problem, can you please provide me the diagram?

Comment: @myts999 See if [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZnwM.png) helps. The cylinder goes "left-right", with the axis of rotation given as the horizontal line $y=2$. The volume is $V=\int dV = \int (2\pi r \cdot h )dy$, where the shell has infinitesimal thickness $dy$, radius $r(y)$ as a function of $y$ is $r = 2-y$, and the "height" $h(y)$ as a function of $y$ is $h = 2-x = 2-2y^2$.

Comment: thanks for the diagram!